# PHP: database migration tool

Tags: php, database-migration, utility

I want a simple database migrations tool for PHP. My main reuqirements:

1. Stand alone solution (no frameworks) with minimum dependencies
2. convinience methods (not just $db->prepare('create table ...')->execute())
3. cli tool (to integrate with deployment system)
4. easily integrated with existing project
5. it shouldn't be abandoned (all solutions i've found had last commits 2-3 years ago and lots of open issues).

I expect it to work with MySQL, no other databases needed.

Any ideas what could it be it?

Comment: Sadly, I've never be able to find such tool, I had the exact same requirements, but all solutions I found were not filling my needs. I end up with Talend Open Studio, which is a bit complex and messy BUT finally do the job pretty well. It is using Java however, but transformations are not that hard.

Comment: I cant understand.. If you use cli.. Best migration tool is set of mysql native tools. Call "mysqldump" and "mysql" binaries directly! Dump DB: `mysqldump -h localhost -u root -ppass dbname > filename.sql`, Restore: `mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword bdname < filename.sql` etc. Learn the params. You will be able to do many cool things with this tools.

Comment: @BogdanBurim do you understand concept of migration? An example: I have a project already in production, after some development I want to roll out new version. With mysqldump I'll reset all data on production. With migrations I'll gracefully migrate to new version.

Comment: I had the same requirements and there's a great new tool called [phinx](http://phinx.org/). Here's an example of a complex migration step I performed: https://coderwall.com/p/v3qg2q

Answer (score 2):

I used [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) in my previous company. It wasn't the most straight forward thing to set up but worked well enough for our requirements. The purpose was to be able to share database migrations in our VCS to make life easier for a small team of 4 developers.

Comment: Seems to be something close, but pretty big.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MySQL](http://mysql.com) directly. It covers all but requirement #2.

> Stand alone solution (no frameworks) with minimum dependencies

Presumably you have MySQL installed. As such, no setup/dependencies.

> cli tool (to integrate with deployment system)

`mysql`, `mysqladmin`, `mysqldump` - [Read more...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html)

> easily integrated with existing project

Again, you have MySQL already.

> it shouldn't be abandoned

Acquired by Sun/Oracle. Not going anywhere.

Comment: Plain SQL doesn't fit: no convinience methods, no easy control (./migrate and database has last state, ./migrate rollback - last migration reverted, ...).

Comment: I noted it doesn't cover that requirement. You aren't going to find an all in one solution. If you managed your migration files so that the *result* was an SQL file, then MySQL could handle the rest.

Comment: How do you track which "migrations" have been run? How do you run a batch of migrations without digging through the file system and writing a dozen `mysql < mig.sql` commands by hand? How do you roll them back?

Comment: I interpret @JasonMcCreary's comment _Acquired by Sun/Oracle. Not going anywhere._, as "having been acquired by a company that has its own db products, [MySQL] is not going anywhere, will eventually develop gangrene and die". Try [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) instead.